# Redshift table not showing up in tables for schema?

Tags: redshift

On Redshift, why doesn't my table show up in the following query? It definitely exists, as shown by the next query I run. I want a way to list all tables for a schema:

```
mydb=# select distinct(tablename) from pg_table_def where schemaname = 'db';
 tablename 
-----------
(0 rows)

mydb=# \d db.some_table
                    Table "db.some_table"
     Column      |            Type             | Modifiers 
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------
...correct info shows up here...
...but nothing showed up above?
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but distinct is not a function. I suggest you remove the parentheses to avoid confusion. On second thought you might as well remove distinct it self since there cannot be two tables with the same name in one schema.

Comment: What is the result of: `select schemaname, tablename from pg_table_def` ?

Comment: Are you sure your schema-name is "db", because it looks like a "database name"?.

Answer (score 15):

[PG_TABLE_DEF](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html) in Redshift only returns information about tables that are visible to the user, in other words, it will only show you the tables which are in the schema(s) which are defined in variable search_path. If PG_TABLE_DEF does not return the expected results, verify that the [search_path parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html) is set correctly to include the relevant schema(s).

Try this -

```
mydb=# set search_path="$user",db;
```

Then run your query -

```
mydb=# select tablename from pg_table_def where schemaname = 'db';
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide more information than 'do this'.

Comment: I think this is the right direction, however I was unable to change `search_path`. After setting it, it still shows `$user,public`.

Answer (score 1):

PG_TABLE_DEF will only return information for tables in schemas that are included in the search path.
[Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html)

Answer (score 1):

In some cases `set search_path TO '$user','schema_1','schema_2';` might not work.
Running `ALTER USER <youruser> SET SEARCH_PATH to '$user','schema_1','schema_2'` should solve it.

Please note that this will permanently change the search path, so in case you want the original search path settings you can run the above `ALTER` command again, with the default search path.